# Compare window-objects

Tags: javascript, window, popupwindow, postmessage

I open a popup-window with:

```
a = window.open('//example.com');
```

From inside this window I send a message with:

```
window.opener.postMessage('test', '*');
```

And receive it with:

```
window.addEventListener('message', e => b = e.source);
```

Because this triggers on **any** message sent to the window, I want to make something like `if(a == b)` to verify wether the message comes from window a. Sadly this always returns `false`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: is your source code working? postMessage need one more parameter to run.

Comment: @songxunzhao You're right, I forgot that. But that's not the point.

Comment: it works on my sample, please check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/q1bfQwWJlsx8eQbGSqEA?p=preview

Comment: @songxunzhao Well, that is strange. Will check this again in my environment. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `.origin` of the `event` and `event.source`.

```
if (event.source.origin === location.protocol + "//example.com"
    && event.origin === location.protocol + "//example.com") {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I know that, but there are several applications on this domain that send messages to my window. So that doesn't help.

Comment: @I'mLu Not sure what you mean? You could alternatively set the `.name` property of the opened `window` to a unique value and post that property value to `.opener`